# SAPUI5 Odata Connection to Server

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

i have a question.. is there a way to get the odata data without a cloud connector? so basicly like http/https://serverip:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/... ?
If i try it trough the browser it works.. i get my metadata.

my manifest looks like this 
[image: manifest]

i tryed it also with http.. but it wont work cause the origin request is a https (webide). The Console says..

[image: console]

i try it already with proxy/ before the ip but almost the same.. the errormessage go away except of one the [ODataMetadata] initial loading of metadata failed - . I even dont get the login popup like before over the cloud connector.. so is there a way to do it like this? that i can develope in the webide? in someday i want that the appilcation i a standalone app. And dont need the scp

thanks guys.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is no way to connect to the backend without a destination/cloud connector created for the system.

Comment: mhmm... when i use eclipse maybe it than works? or i can only work with ajax requests?

Comment: It works because you will mostly have a proxy servlet running. Just to be clear, it is not specific to Web IDE. The basic reasoning behind the 'CORS' error you see is because www.a.com cannot call www.b.com, unless the b website has a in its list of sites allowed to get info from it. Therefore, here, webide and the backend system cannot directly talk to each other, unless a destination for the system in maintained.

Comment: Yeah i get overall the CORS error.. is there a way to fix it? i try it already with my localhost.. and with the webide both CORS error.. so is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAP Web IDE, the easiest way to do it, would be to add a Destination for your backend system in SAP Cloud Platform, and then add an OData service using that Destination in SAP Web IDE (this will create entries in manifest.json and create wiring to the destination in neo-app.json). As your particular endpoint works through your browser, you wouldn't need to use Cloud Connector.